# Hibernate cascade types or something else?

Tags: java, hibernate, cascade, many-to-one

I am trying to find a bug in an application I haven’t written.

The scenario is that the user creates an application and after that creates a product which is attached to it. Application has a reference to the Product and vice versa. The problem is that the product isn't getting the applications ID and I can't figure out where is the problem. At some time in the past it worked put during the development it got broken.

I read that the CascadeType should do the syncing. I don't know much about it but they seem odd:

```
class Product {
  @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
  Application application;
}

class Application {
  @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.REFRESH})
  Product product;
}
```

So are the types set correctly? Should I search for the problem from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

This should not be a problem with the cascade, because cascade only becomes active if an object gets deleted. This could more be a problem with ur mapping or the save method of the object.

Comment: You are probably right. Saving methods are so complex in it. I'll check it out.